# Letter O with vertical line: operator null

Tags: math-operators

I wan to know how this letter O with a vertical line for operator null in maths. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `\mathds{O}` from `dsfont` package.

Comment: thanks so much, just what i need it

Comment: Hi! Your question is likely to be closed, as it has a relevant answer posted in another thread. Don't take it personally: it's just because it makes this site much more relevant!

Answer (score 4):

`\mathds{O}` from `dsfont` package.

Easy to find on [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathds{O} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]